# Is a hypersurface really defined by an arbitrary polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

In An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry Karen Smith writes at the beginning of the book:

> The zero set of a single polynomial in arbitrary dimension is called a
>   hypersurface in $\mathbb C^n$. The quadratic cone is a typical example
>   of a hypersurface.

I believe I have come across the term hypersurface before and I believe that it was used to mean that in $\mathbb R^n$ a hypersurface is an $n-1$ dimensional manifold.

As a consequence I expect the definition of hypersurface in the context of algebraic geometry to mean a variety of dimension $n-1$.

Consider for example $\mathbb R^2$ and the polynomial $p(x,y) = xy$. This is the two axes and is a variety of dimension $1$. (According to the perhaps naive definition given in the book so far.)

Since I was still skeptical I tried to find a different book giving the defnition of hypersurface and so I came across [Hartshorne](https://books.google.com/books?id=7z4mBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA7&ots=OO61srqlhR&dq=dimension%20of%20the%20zero%20set%20of%20one%20polynomial&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Proposition 1.13: A variety $Y$ in $\mathbb A^n$ has dimension $n-1$
>   if and only if it is the zero set $Z(f)$ of a single nonconstant
>   irreducible polynomial in $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.

Assuming my understanding of the term hypersurface is correct this proposition adds the condition of irreducibility to the polynomial. As a consequence I would expect the zero sets of reducible polynomials to not be hypersurfaces.

So I tried to find the simplest example possible. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$ the polynomial $p(x,y) = x^2 - 4 $ [is reducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#Simple_examples).

But the graph (using [this online grapher](http://www.flashandmath.com/mathlets/calc/implicit/implicit.html)) of $x^2 - 4 = 0$ is, as expected, two vertical lines. Which, according to my current naive understanding of dimension of a variety, is indeed an $n-1=1$ dimensional variety.

> Please could someone help me resolve my confusion?

Comment: well, it depends on your definition of hypersurface. Sometimes it is convenient to define them tto be irreducible, sometimes not, depending on what you are doing. There is nothing sacred about the word *hypersurface*, so this is perfectly good! That is why one has to check what meanings the author one is reading is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) An algebraic subset  $X\subset\mathbb C^n$ has all its irreducible components of dimension $n-1$ if and only if   it is the zero set $X=V(P)$ of some  non-constant polynomial $P\in \mathbb C[T_1,...,T_n]$.

b) Beware that  $X=\{(1,0)\}\cup V(T_1)\subset \mathbb C^2$ is an algebraic subset of dimension $1$ (=the maximum  dimension of its irreducible components) but is not equal to any $V(P)$ because one its irreducible components, namely $\{(1,0)\}=V(T_1-1,T_2)$, has dimension $0\neq n-1=2-1$.

Comment: I have deliberately abstained from using the words "hypersurface" and "variety" in order to have (I hope) completely unambiguous statements.

Comment: In a), I think you need to add that the polynomial is nonzero.

Comment: @Alistair Savage. You are right and I have modified my statement accordingly. Thank you for your vigilance.